# Python Tkinter fixing text location on scrolling screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to scroll a graphic on the screen while keeping the text in the same place.  The text shows where the mouse is located.  I've thought about the idea of scrolling the text in the opposite direction of the screen scroll but I'm not sure if there is an easier way of doing it and if I have to scroll the text the opposite way I'm not sure how to set the initial text pointer so I can come back and recall/reset it.  I'm only wanting it to show the position on  not  as  will be doing other things in the near future.

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.keys = dict.fromkeys(('Left', 'Right', 'Up', 'Down'))

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="bisque", width=700, height=700)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(-1000, -1000, 1000, 1000))

        self.looper() # start the looping

    def keypress(self,event):
        if event.keysym in self.keys:
        # event type 2 is key down, type 3 is key up
            self.keys[event.keysym] = event.type == '2'

    def looper(self):
        if self.keys['Up']:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-2,'units')
        if self.keys['Down']:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(2,'units')
        if self.keys['Left']:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(-2,'units')
        if self.keys['Right']:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(2,'units')

        self.after(5, self.looper) # set the refresh rate here ... ie 20 milliseconds. Smaller number means faster scrolling

    def on_press(self, event):
        self.last_x = event.x
        self.last_y = event.y
        self.startx, self.starty = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x),self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete("sx")
        self.startx, self.starty = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x),self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        px = round(-(((1000-self.startx) * .00015) + 69.3),5)
        py = round((45.05-((1000+self.starty) * .00015)),5)
        self.canvas.create_text(400,-400, text = str(px), fill = "black", tags = "sx")
        self.canvas.create_text(475,-400, text = str(py), fill = "black", tags = "sx")

    def button_motion(self,event):
        delta_x = event.x - self.last_x
        delta_y = event.y - self.last_y
        self.last_x = event.x
        self.last_y = event.y

        self.canvas.xview_scroll(-delta_x, "units")
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-delta_y, "units")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a widget that is not embedded in the canvas for the text so that it won't scroll when the canvas scrolls. Create a `Label` with it's parent being the canvas, and then use `place` to superimpose the label on top of the canvas.